# Ajax load percentage on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have many ajax call on page loads. Sometimes i even have nested ajax calls.
like this

```
function getAll(){
    $.when(http_get('url1')).then(function(response){
        $.when(http_get('url2')).then(function(response){
            $.when(http_get('url3')).then(function(response){
```

Now how can i get the overall ajax loading percentage to show in my preloader.

Comment: successfullRequests / amountRequests

Comment: How do i get successfullRequests or amountRequests ?

Comment: success callback from your ajax call has to increase a counter. that's it.